# How can I know how much free ram i have left on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, ram

I don't know how to see a graphical representation of how much ram i have left.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command in a terminal to show your available amount of RAM:

```
free -h
```

The output should look something like this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4.8G       4.5G       266M       209M       888K       3.0G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.5G       3.3G
Swap:         6.3G        40M       6.2G
```

As you can see in this example, there is 266M free RAM including cached RAM. There is 3.3G available, not including the cache.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways.

1. `free` command

   ```
   free --human
   free --help
   ```
2. `cat /proc/meminfo`
3. `vmstat` reports virtual memory statistics

   ```
   vmstat --stats --unit m
   ```
4. `top` or `htop`

Answer (score 2):

I like graphical representation ... in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install htop
$ htop
```

Answer (score 1):

For a graphical display of memory usage you can add the corresponding Resource Monitor item to the panel.  Do it like this:

- Right-click the panel
- Select Add / Remove Panel Items
- Click + Add
- Click Resource Monitors
- Click + Add
- Click Resource Monitors in the list
- Click Edit
- Tick the box beside Display RAM Usage
- Click Close

Answer (score 0):

The 'Task Manager' application that is found in the 'System Tools' menu will show you a live view of your memory usage, though this is a number based readout.

If you'd like to see the information in a more visual format, I believe it's possible to install `system-monitor` which is the graphical application which comes with regular Ubuntu as standard.

To do this from a terminal, do :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor
```